# What are the minimum requirements for a level 3 Garrison?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

As of August 9th, the Demon Hunter class has been released in World of Warcraft. These characters start at level 98, and by the time they've finished their starting zone are going to be at least level 100. However, by default they aren't granted any progress in the Warlords of Draenor content - they have to start from square one.

Much of the content and/or bonuses exclusive to Garrisons can only fully be realized by a level 3 Garrison. What is the minimum amount of work I have to do to be able to upgrade my Garrison to level 3?

Comment: TL;DR: Work: some resource farming (farm treasures!). Gold: 5k for lvl 3 + building costs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you have to complete the intial garrison quest chain, which ends with establishing your outpost and building barracks level 1. You right away receive the quest to upgrade it to level 2 (you need 200 garrison resources for that). This can be done within 1.5h maximum, starting in your capital (tested today in the morning).
After that, you are directly offered the quest to upgrade your garrison to level 3, but you need 2000 garrison resources for that step. Farming this amount of resources the conventional way takes a lot of time. An alternative to that is buying two [Huge Ogre Caches](http://www.wowhead.com/item=128313/huge-ogre-cache) from the auction house. Not cheap, but it does the trick.

A comment from my side: You have to decide yourself if it is worth the trouble, depending on what you want to do with your demon hunter. You can participate in all raids etc. without spending many days or 10k gold on your level 3 garrison. If you only want to level your new professions, constructing the respective buildings to level 2 might suffice until the start of the expansion.

Comment: Given that level 3 garrison cost 5000 gold. You might want to do the quest chain that let you earn a Bind on Account weapon upgrade to 100 which cost 5000 gold itself plus a few other rewards. Otherwise your answer looks good.

Comment: You can circle the continent for Treasure. This gives you the required Garrison ressources in no time without spending extra Gold. The initial costs are already high enough.